# Are there fonts that have both italic and oblique variants?

Tags: fonts, styles

I would like to know if there are fonts I can download that come in both italic and oblique styles.

I tried searching on the web, really I did. And there are always millions of results! But none of those results are what I'm looking for, they're all pages that explain what the differences are between italic and oblique. I know that! I know what the differences are!

Oh yeah, some of those pages go as far as to mention, in an offhand manner, "there are also fonts that come in both italic and oblique styles", but they never say which ones! So I never get any further!

All I want is to have both Xxxx Italic and Xxxx Oblique on my computer. Is that too much to ask?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking us. Of course fonts with variations exist.  Are you asking how to search for/locate them on the web?  If so, that's off-topic; and there are MANY font-specific sites on the web you could use.  If you're not asking that, then please edit your question to clarify what your (on-topic) question to us is.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I'm sorry, I have no idea how to make it more clear what I want. Could you name an example of such a font family, and how you found it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Are there fonts that have both italic and oblique variants?

Most typefaces have *either* oblique *or* italic variants **but not both**.

> **Few typefaces have both oblique and italic designs**, as this is generally a fundamental design choice about how the font should look.
>   A font designer will normally decide to design their font with one or
>   the other.

Source [Oblique type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblique_type)

---

#### Are there any exceptions?

> LUCIDA GRANDE LIGHT and LUCIDA GRANDE BLACK fonts are available in
>   roman, **italic**, and **oblique** styles from the Lucida Fonts Store. These
>   newly released styles for the Lucida Grande family are offered in the
>   pan-European WGL character set.
>
> The LUCIDA GRANDE font family is now available in four weights: Light,
>   Normal, Bold, and Black; and in three styles for each weight: Roman,
>   **Italic**, and **Oblique**. Narrow versions of all four weights and three
>   styles are also available from the Lucida Fonts Store.

Source [Lucida Font Store FAQ](http://lucidafonts.com/pages/faq):

---

#### Actually I was hoping for a font that was a free download

- [Latin Modern Roman](http://fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman) ([Licence](http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt)) is free.

Comment: Thank you! So at least now I know for sure there's at least one font out there that has both styles. They do exist! How did you find this one? Actually I was hoping for a font that was a free download.

Comment: It's on the first page of a google search for "font with both and italic oblique" ... I didn't look for more examples :/

Comment: Here is a free one http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/latin-modern-roman

Comment: Thanks for the link. That particular font, Latin Modern Roman, doesn't qualify though. The oblique font has a different family name than the italic one. So technically, those are two distinct fonts! I'm still searching.

Comment: Meanwhile, I did discover that I could use the __fontforge__ application to turn existing fonts into slanted ones. So my immediate problem is solved now, I can just take any font that has an italic variant and then make a new slanted variant from the regular one. It looks horrible of course, but that's a lesser concern...